# Flutter Flat Button Color Property Not Working

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In flutter App I'm trying to set color for the FlatButton But it's not working. find the source code below.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            FlatButton(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            FlatButton(
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            FlatButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: My Code Output]

I'm flutter Beginner, Any Idea What is the issue in my code?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to provide child and onPressed parameter in order to render the widget, else it won't render, which results in non working UI.

Check out the code i modified :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            FlatButton(
              color: Colors.red,
              onPressed:()=>printData(),
              child: Text("click"),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              color: Colors.green,
              onPressed:()=>printData(),
              child: Text("click"),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
              onPressed:()=>printData(),
              child: Text("click"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

void printData(){
  print('Hello');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the @required fields of the FlatButton Constructor without which it would not render.
[image: constructor]

This is a Flat button with required fields. Add your desired color to this to render it.
Without a color it renders with black text and white background.

```
FlatButton(
  onPressed: () {
    /*...*/
  },
  child: Text(
    "Flat Button",
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it's very useful to me

Comment: glad that it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem. I just added "disabledColor : Colors.red"
Check screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJAG8.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post code directly in the answer rather than as a screenshot

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot what you exactly got in mobile devices. If that button colour is not apply?

Comment: Inside set null to onpress method please use any of the dummy method. So we can trail and error to find to solution for this